# Drawing an ellipse on iOS using Swift, Metal and fragment shader

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, metal

I'm new to Swift and Metal and I'm trying to create a simple rendering engine for iOS just for learning purposes. So, I am stuck with drawing a simple ellipse using fragment shader function.  What I am actually doing is that I am rendering a quad, passing normalized device coordinates of the top left and bottom right vertices of that quad and finally in the fragment shader I calculate if each fragment is inside the ellipse. I've already done that in OpenGL and it worked fine. I am not sure if that is the proper way to render an ellipse, but this approach does not seem to work in Metal.

So, here are the shader functions:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct EllipseIn {
    float4 position [[attribute(0)]];
    float4 color [[attribute(1)]];
    float3 tlPosition [[attribute(2)]];
    float3 brPosition [[attribute(3)]];
};

struct EllipseOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float4 color;
    float3 tlPosition [[flat]];
    float3 brPosition [[flat]];
};

vertex EllipseOut ellipse_vertex(const EllipseIn ellipseIn [[stage_in]]) {
    EllipseOut ellipseOut;
    ellipseOut.position = ellipseIn.position;
    ellipseOut.color = ellipseIn.color;
    ellipseOut.tlPosition = ellipseIn.tlPosition;
    ellipseOut.brPosition = ellipseIn.brPosition;
    return ellipseOut;
}

fragment float4 ellipse_fragment(EllipseOut ellipseIn [[stage_in]]) {
    float3 t = (ellipseIn.brPosition - ellipseIn.tlPosition) / 2;
    float a = t.x;
    float b = t.y;
    float x = ellipseIn.position.x;
    float y = ellipseIn.position.y;
    float xc = ellipseIn.tlPosition.x + a;
    float yc = ellipseIn.tlPosition.y + b;
    float x2 = x - xc;
    float y2 = y - yc;
    float c = x2 / a;
    float d = y2 / b;
    float res = c * c + d * d;
    
    if (res > 1)
        discard_fragment();

    return ellipseIn.color;
}
```

And here is the Swift code:

```
import Foundation
import MetalKit

struct EllipseVertexDescriptor {
    var position: SIMD4<Float>
    var color: SIMD4<Float>
    var tlPosition: SIMD3<Float>
    var brPosition: SIMD3<Float>
}

class EllipseRenderer : PrimitiveRenderer {
    private var pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!
    
    func preparePipelineState(device: MTLDevice, library: MTLLibrary) {
        let ellipseVertexFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "ellipse_vertex")
        let ellipseFragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "ellipse_fragment")

        let ellipsePipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        ellipsePipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = ellipseVertexFunction
        ellipsePipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = ellipseFragmentFunction
        ellipsePipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
        ellipsePipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true

        let ellipseVertexDescriptor = MTLVertexDescriptor()
        
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[0].format = .float4
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[0].offset = 0
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0
        
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[1].format = .float4
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[1].offset = MemoryLayout<SIMD4<Float>>.stride
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[1].bufferIndex = 0
        
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[2].format = .float3
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[2].offset = MemoryLayout<SIMD4<Float>>.stride + MemoryLayout<SIMD4<Float>>.stride
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[2].bufferIndex = 0
        
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[3].format = .float3
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[3].offset = MemoryLayout<SIMD4<Float>>.stride + MemoryLayout<SIMD4<Float>>.stride + MemoryLayout<SIMD3<Float>>.stride
        ellipseVertexDescriptor.attributes[3].bufferIndex = 0

        ellipseVertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stride = MemoryLayout<EllipseVertexDescriptor>.stride

        ellipsePipelineDescriptor.vertexDescriptor = ellipseVertexDescriptor

        pipelineState = try! device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: ellipsePipelineDescriptor)
    }

    func render(device: MTLDevice, encoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder, primitive: MetalPrimitive) {
        var mp = primitive
        guard let gp = mp.data as? CliGeometryPrimitiveData,
              let tlp = gp.tlPositionN, //top left position in normalized device coordinates
              let brp = gp.brPositionN, //bottom right position in normalized device coordinates
              let fillColor = gp.fillColorN else {return}

        if (mp.redraw) {
            let vertices: [EllipseVertexDescriptor] = [
                EllipseVertexDescriptor(
                    position: SIMD4<Float>(tlp.x, tlp.y, 0, 1),
                    color: SIMD4<Float>(fillColor.x, fillColor.y, fillColor.z, fillColor.w),
                    tlPosition: SIMD3<Float>(tlp.x, tlp.y, 0),
                    brPosition: SIMD3<Float>(brp.x, brp.y, 0)
                ),
                EllipseVertexDescriptor(
                    position: SIMD4<Float>(tlp.x, brp.y, 0, 1),
                    color: SIMD4<Float>(fillColor.x, fillColor.y, fillColor.z, fillColor.w),
                    tlPosition: SIMD3<Float>(tlp.x, tlp.y, 0),
                    brPosition: SIMD3<Float>(brp.x, brp.y, 0)
                ),
                EllipseVertexDescriptor(
                    position: SIMD4<Float>(brp.x, brp.y, 0, 1),
                    color: SIMD4<Float>(fillColor.x, fillColor.y, fillColor.z, fillColor.w),
                    tlPosition: SIMD3<Float>(tlp.x, tlp.y, 0),
                    brPosition: SIMD3<Float>(brp.x, brp.y, 0)
                ),
                EllipseVertexDescriptor(
                    position: SIMD4<Float>(brp.x, tlp.y, 0, 1),
                    color: SIMD4<Float>(fillColor.x, fillColor.y, fillColor.z, fillColor.w),
                    tlPosition: SIMD3<Float>(tlp.x, tlp.y, 0),
                    brPosition: SIMD3<Float>(brp.x, brp.y, 0)
                ),
            ]

            let indicies: [UInt16] = [
                0, 1, 2,
                2, 3, 0,
            ]

            mp.vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices, length: vertices.count * MemoryLayout<EllipseVertexDescriptor>.stride, options: [])
            mp.indexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: indicies, length: indicies.count * MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size, options: [])
        }

        encoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
        encoder.setVertexBuffer(mp.vertexBuffer!, offset: 0, index: 0)
        encoder.drawIndexedPrimitives(type: .triangle, indexCount: 6, indexType: .uint16, indexBuffer: mp.indexBuffer!, indexBufferOffset: 0)
    }
}
```

The result of the above code is that all fragments are being discarded.

What am I missing?
Any help would be appreciated.